# How to stop a background process when the foreground process finished completing the task

Tags: bash, scripts, process

Need to stop b.sh when a.sh is finished. Both scripts must run in parallel one must not wait for the other. b.sh contains the profiling of the process a.sh. When I run the script while loop does not stop. I couldn't use $! to kill the background process because other processes are running in the background created from a.sh script file.

Contents of a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
pid=$$
export pid
./b.sh &
b_id=$!
#load time
docker load<ubuntu.tar
id=$(docker images -a | awk '{print $3}' | awk 'NR==2')
docker run -t --rm $id
echo "Container started"
pkill -P $b_id
```

Contents of b.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
some profiling code
done
```

Comment: Is the code after the second shebang contained in your b.sh script?

Comment: Yes @Arronical this is the second shebang b.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `pkill`, which is normally used to find a PID from a pattern such as the process name, as you already have the PID of the `b.sh` script. Just using plain old kill will do, replace:

```
pkill -P $b_id
```

with:

```
kill $b_id
```

I'm guessing that you used `pkill -P $Pb_id` as you want to kill all child processes of `b.sh`, this command kills all of the child processes, but not the process itself. There's no problem in using them both, so `pkill` all of the child processes first, then `kill` the parent process.